# SQL Server 2008 sync 2 tables using triggers

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, multiple-records

I'm new to SQL Server triggers.

I have 2 tables (one master and one slave) with a primary on multiple columns.

I need to create a trigger on first table in order to synchronize the second table. In which way could I manage an update on multiple rows on a column on primary key?

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Seasons]
(
    [Entity] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Seasons] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Entity] ASC, [Code] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 10) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Seasons2]
(
    [Entity] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Seasons2] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Entity] ASC, [Code] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 10) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [Seasons] VALUES ('XX','11','Test')
INSERT INTO [Seasons] VALUES ('XX','22','Test')
INSERT INTO [Seasons] VALUES ('XX','33','Test')

UPDATE [Seasons] 
SET Entity = 'YY'
```

In the worst case, could I iterate over inserted and deleted tables? These tables are in the same order?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The fact that you have a primary key that is obviously up for changes makes it nearly impossible to write an `UPDATE` trigger...... this is generally a **bad idea** anyway .... I would recommend to change your design - if `Entity` and `Code` really can change - don't use those as PK - use an  `INT IDENTITY` that's **immutable** as your PK instead

Comment: than you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, i didn't design the database and i cannot change tables structure. Is it possible to iterate over INSERTED and DELETED table at the same time and compare records? The two tables have the same order? For example third row of inserted table in the previous value of third row in DELETED table?

Comment: ***don't even think about ITERATING!!!*** This is **horribly bad** in a relational database - and most horrible in a trigger!! There is ***NO ORDER*** in those tables - you have to be able to identify the rows **via their primary key** - that's the **only reliable way** to go!!